# Error when starting node - Ubuntu server 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: node, ubuntu

I am receiving below error when starting the Tezos service. I have installed on the laptop with success so it must be something with the environment but I cannot wrap my head around it...

```
Feb 12 00:32:13 boomStaker tezos-node-start[54569]: Feb 12 00:32:13.992 - node.main: starting the Tezos node (chain = TEZOS_MAINNET)
Feb 12 00:32:13 boomStaker tezos-node-start[54569]: Feb 12 00:32:13.992 - node.main: disabled local peer discovery
Feb 12 00:32:13 boomStaker tezos-node-start[54569]: Feb 12 00:32:13.996 - node: shell-node initialization: bootstrapping
Feb 12 00:32:13 boomStaker tezos-node-start[54569]: Feb 12 00:32:13.998 - p2p.welcome: cannot accept incoming connections
Feb 12 00:32:13 boomStaker tezos-node-start[54569]: tezos-node: Error:
Feb 12 00:32:13 boomStaker tezos-node-start[54569]:               Unix error in socket: Address family not supported by protocol
Feb 12 00:32:13 boomStaker tezos-node-start[54569]:             
Feb 12 00:32:14 boomStaker systemd[1]: tezos.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 12 00:32:14 boomStaker systemd[1]: tezos.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 12 00:32:19 boomStaker systemd[1]: tezos.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 32.
```

Here is the commands I run:

```
sudo tezos-node identity generate --data-dir /mnt/sda1/tezos/
- Stored the new identity (idtjwGHCJ8TnqkRn5kurdeAD7o2rJT) into '/mnt/sda1/tezos/identity.json'.

sudo tezos-node config init --data-dir /mnt/sda1/tezos/
Created /mnt/sda1/tezos/config.json for default network: mainnet.

sudo tezos-node run --data-dir /mnt/sda1/tezos/
Feb 12 09:38:26.473 - node.main: read identity file (peer_id = idtjwGHCJ8TnqkRn5kurdeAD7o2rJT)
Feb 12 09:38:26.473 - node.main: starting the Tezos node.... tezos-node: Error: Unix error in socket: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: Show the command you are using to start tezos-node

Comment: For more logging information you can try running `LWT_LOG="* -> debug" tezos-node ...`

Comment: The command I am using is tezos-node run or systemctl start tezos.service (which is just a copy of the tezos-node-mainet.service with a customn --data-dir

Comment: sudo tezos-node identity generate --data-dir /mnt/sda1/tezos/ - Stored the new identity (idtjwGHCJ8TnqkRn5kurdeAD7o2rJT) into '/mnt/sda1/tezos/identity.json'. sudo tezos-node config init --data-dir /mnt/sda1/tezos/
Created /mnt/sda1/tezos/config.json for default network: mainnet. sudo tezos-node run --data-dir /mnt/sda1/tezos/
Feb 12 09:38:26.473 - node.main: read identity file (peer_id = idtjwGHCJ8TnqkRn5kurdeAD7o2rJT)
Feb 12 09:38:26.473 - node.main: starting the Tezos node....
tezos-node: Error: Unix error in socket: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: has this something to do that ipv6 is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are using the default identity, this identity should look like this :

```
    { "bootstrap-peers":
        [ "boot.tzbeta.net", "116.202.172.21", "95.216.45.62" ],
      "listen-addr": "[::]:9732" } }
```

the address "[::]:9732" is an ipv6 address, try replacing it with its ipv4 equivalent "0.0.0.0:9732"

Comment: yes you are right but I am still facing issues with the RPC addr. If IPv6 is disabled in OS and the config.json contains  "rpc": { "listen-addr": "0.0.0.0:8733" } the tezos-node refuses to start. If I enable the IPV6, no changes in the config, I can still see in the logs:node.main: starting RPC server on ::ffff:0.0.0.0:8733, so its like it ignores the conf and wants to listen also on ipv6. i have changed the port to 8733, so i can verify its loading the correct config...